# Content of PDF needs to overflows to next page with same structure

Tags: java, c#, pdf, itext

I am using itextsharp v 5.5.13 to create PDF documents.

One scenario where I need help is where the PDF document has a structure (header, body and footer like a template). The idea is to populate data only in the body section. Whenever there is overflow of data to next page, the data goes into the body of the next page maintaining the same structure (i.e. with header and footer).

Currently, I am able to achieve the same by creating pageeventhelper where on page start and page end, I am adding the header and footer. With this approach, I am able to get the desired result but it appears to be little hacky, and the appearance is also not that great (white spaces , gaps etc).

Any suggestions of a better way to handle this use case?

The code looks like as follows,

in the PdfPageEventHelper i have two different headers for page 1 and page 2, and a footer,

```
protected PdfPTable primaryHeader;
protected PdfPTable secondaryHeader;
protected PdfPTable footer;

public void setPrimaryHeader(PdfPTable header)
{
    this.primaryHeader = header;
}

public void setSecondaryHeader(PdfPTable header)
{
    this.secondaryHeader = header;
}

public void setFooter(PdfPTable footer)
{
    this.footer = footer;
}

public override void OnStartPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
{
    base.OnStartPage(writer, document);

    if (writer.PageNumber == 1)
    {
        this.primaryHeader.TotalWidth = document.Right - document.Left;
        this.primaryHeader.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, 10, document.Top + 40, writer.DirectContent);
        // Adding extra space to remove overlap of text
        document.Add(PdfHelper.GetEmptyTable(200f));
    }
    else
    {
        this.secondaryHeader.TotalWidth = document.Right - document.Left;
        this.secondaryHeader.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, 10, document.Top + 40, writer.DirectContent);
        // Adding extra space to remove overlap of text
        document.Add(PdfHelper.GetEmptyTable(60f));
    }
}

public override void OnEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
{
    base.OnEndPage(writer, document);

    this.footer.TotalWidth = document.Right - document.Left;
    this.footer.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, 10, document.Bottom + 10, writer.DirectContent);
}
```

The following code creates the byte array pdf,

```
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10, 10, 42, 35);
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, stream);
    CustomPageEventHelper peh = new CustomPageEventHelper(true);
    peh.setPrimaryHeader(GetPrimaryHeader(response, identity));
    peh.setSecondaryHeader(GetSecondaryHeader(response, identity));
    peh.setFooter(GetFooter(response, identity));
    writer.PageEvent = peh;

    document.Open();

    PdfPTable table = null;
    PdfPTable tableOuter = null;
    PdfPTable tableInner = null;
    PdfPTable tableGrid = null;
    PdfPCell cell = null;

    // Adding content here via PdfPTable's

    document.Close();
    result = stream.ToArray();
}
```

The following is the output,
[image]

Comment: Using page events is appropriate for adding headers and footers. It's not hacky as a concept. Whether your code is, I cannot tell. *"the appearance is also not that great"* - if you explained what you mean by this (what you get compared to what you want) and showed the pivotal code, we might help improving your solution.

Comment: i just updated the question with code snippets and sample output. Another problem I am facing is that when I make the table height standard, the content pushing to 3rd page onwards, leaving the first and second page empty.

Comment: First of all, iText developers repeatedly stressed that one should never add content to a page in `OnStartPage`, only in `OnEndPage`; in certain situations adding content in `OnStartPage` can result in unneeded pages. Furthermore, they stress that in a page event listener content shall only be added via the `PdfWriter writer`, never the `Document document`; the latter object is available merely to retrieve information about the document layout, e.g. margins.

Comment: That been said, you could fix the gaps by experimenting and correcting the `WriteSelectedRows` parameters. But as you want to have the lines and boxes to be page filling anyways and not limited to the added content, I would draw *all* the lines on page 2 onwards, in particular the vertical ones, in the page event listener. That way iText's layout'ing won't disturb the lines.

Comment: Furthermore, as you have a different header on page 1, why don't you simply use a very small top margin on page 1 and add that starting header as initial regular content?